# Как примонтировать SMB шару в кастомном дистрибутиве linux?

Tags: linux, samba, asterisk, mount

Есть железная АТС на базе астериска, на ней установлен linux, в GUI есть настройка SMB шары, работает исправно.
Но я ни никак не могу сделать тоже самое через SSH, вообще следов smb клиента нету, стоит только один smb демон (smbd который)
smbmount нету, пробывал mount с типом ФС smbfs так он мне сказал, что незнает такого типа ФС. В etc валяется папка samba но там ни одного конфига нету. 
Собственно можно как-то узнать как происходит общение с расшаренной папкой у ОС?

Comment: find / -print | egrep '(samb|smb|cifs)'. Если точнее: mount.cifs в системе есть?

Comment: @donRumata спасибо, cifs же и правда, и конфиг сразу нашел где лежит. Блин, какая же крутая все-таки и линукса консоль!

Comment: Ну тогда камент в ответы, если цифс заработал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету в комментарии **donRumata**, я выполнил поиск, следующим образом

```
find / -print | egrep '(samb|smb|cifs)'
```

Сразу обнаружилось и наличие cifs и пути к самому конфигу samba, заменил в fstab smbfs на cifs все заработало!